# I've two computers.. But which one I keep? which one is better? HP vs Asus

Tags: memory, graphics-card, cpu

I've two computers Asus and Hp:

**HP EliteBook 8560w has this configuration:**

Intel® Core™ i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz × 8

DDR3 8GiB

NVIDIA Quadro 1000M avec 2 GB

**Asus G553V gamer has:**

Intel Core i5-6300HQ CPU @ 2.3 - 3.2 GHz

DDR4 8GiB

NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M

I don't play games or video editing..etc 
My job is mainly image processing using C++ which uses lot of math and geometry..etc.

About multithreading, I believe that compilers are very intelligent that they can use threads automatically if that is possible.. So I think it will useful in my case

What do you think? which machine is suitable for me?

Comment: any good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.  "which machine is suitable for me?" - Only you can answer this question.

Comment: @Ramhound  So you think that the two machines are the same?

Comment: Diwnload one of the benchmarking software programs, run it on both, then read the results and make your decision

Comment: That HP has  a Nviidia Quadro card, the Asus probably some Geforce model. They might both be 2 GB but the difference in GPU chipsets is significant. You will have to give us exact specifications. You also omitted the clock-speed of the Asus. And your software... Is it heavily multi-threaded or not... That is also important.

Comment: @Tonny yes you're right, I just edited my question

Comment: @Ja_cpp The newer computer is significantly better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right.. After your edit added some useful information...

The Asus is the newer, more modern machine. The HP is already 5 year old or so.

The i5 in the Asus has more cache, a higher clock-speed and faster RAM than the i7 in the HP. There is no hyper-threading.
The i7 has 4 cores + hyper-threading (which amounts to 8 cores if used effectively by your software), but is slower in all aspects. The i7 is only interesting if you are heavily into multi-threaded applications using more than 4 threads. (Probably only really noticeable until you go beyond 8 threads.)

The Quadro in the HP only makes sense if you have software that insists on (or is heavily optimized for) a Quadro card (some specialist 3D CAD software falls in that category).
For everything else the GTX960 will be the faster/better video-card.

In short: The Asus is the better machine, except for the rare case if you really need a Quadro GPU or are using heavily multi-threaded software most of the time.

Comment: Even with HT you're only looking at 10%-30% faster compilation from the 8 threads, vs 4 threads on the same architecture. Not anywhere near the 100% one might think. The newer architecture should itself account for the lack of HT, perhaps better even. See also, https://blog.regehr.org/archives/1416, https://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare.php?cmp[]=2632&cmp[]=873

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the Asus G553V. If you don't require 4C/8T, than the processor gives you 4C at higher speed than the i7-2630QM. The speed is very similar and the architecture is also 5 years newer.

It also uses DDR4 memory with lower consumption than DDR3.

The graphics isn't important for you, despite that the 960M has lower consumption and gives you more functions like acceleration of video content and so on.

So from the future usability perspective, it's better option. And also, it's much younger HW, so there is lower chance, that some HW part fails.

You didn't specified the display parameters and disk type (HDD/SSD). It can be also significant decision factor...